# Creating a input link button

Tags: html, input

hello all a quick question..

i am building a static html page, and would like to like one page to another using a button, now using a link is the easier option but i would like the effect of a button without any javascript going off..

so i would like to use a input button but it to link to a html page like an  tag can href.

i was thinking along the lines of this example but without the js..

```
<form>
  <input type="button" value="Read more" class="button" onclick="window.location.href='testimonials.html'">
</form>
```

this doesnt work but i am looking for this functionality?? is it possible?

Comment: But you're just writing JavaScript in your example!

Comment: Excuse me for the giggles, but `onlick` is actually `onclick` I assume... (not to mention, this is already JavaScript). Why do you want to avoid that?

Comment: i know there is js in the example i want that functionality without the js.. sorry if i didnt explain that properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just submit the form to the URL.

```
<form action="testimonials.html">
  <input type="submit" value="Read more">
</form>
```

… but buttons are supposed to do stuff. Links go places. Don't send people mixed messages, use a link.

Comment: @AlvinWong — No, you don't. My answer demonstrates that normal form submission will work.

Comment: @Quentin Well I know that I've delivered some wrong idea (or not so clearly), but I still agree with what you says, buttons are not for normal navigation. This solution should be accepted, but I really suggest the OP not to use this solution even though this works. Use a link instead.

Comment: dude you are a legend. everyone was laughing at me here at work that id need js, or id need some sort of framework. i wish i could buy you a do-nut cause your that awesome

Answer (score 1):

you've misspelled "onclick" :)

EDIT: if you want to avoid javascript, you can create a button-like link with CSS:

```
<a href="testimonials.html" style="display: inline-block; border: 1px solid #AAA; background-color: #CCC; margin: 5px; width: 100px; cursor: pointer; text-align: center; color: #000; text-decoration: none;">Read More</a>
```

Comment: i just made that dirty didnt i lol.. well yes but the css i am using requires i use a div so i am going and people oftern click on the div and not the a tag.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
<form>
  <input type="button" value="Read more" class="button" onlick="window.location='testimonials.html'">
</form>
```

Comment: That won't work (you misspelt `onclick`). This seems to be largely the same as the code in the question, so what has changed and why? The question says "Without any JavaScript".